# Why cw CodeSnippet generates global::System.Console.WriteLine();

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

Considering this short version of my code written in Dot Net 6's new-console-template as per below:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var opt = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>()
    .UseSqlite("ConnectionString...").Options;
using var dbCon = new MyDbContext(opt);

dbCon.Authors.Include(a => a.Books.Where(b => b.PublicationYear > 2021)).ToList().ForEach(author =>
{
    // cw generates following model
    global::System.Console.WriteLine();
});

// cw acting normal
Console.WriteLine();


new List<object>().ForEach(a =>
{
    // cw acting normal
    Console.WriteLine();
});
```

When using `cw` CodeSnippet inside `dbCon.Authors.Include...` block, Visual Studio generates `global::System.Console.WriteLine();` but in the other scenario's as I mentioned in the above code, its normal.

I'm using:

> Visual Studio 2022 Version 17.1.5

Is it a bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: Think about how C# resolves names, and all the ways that an ambiguous name might appear in code. Prefixing everything with `global::` ensures that the name is unambiguous, and it's easy to generate. Not adding that prefix requires in depth knowledge of how C# will resolve names, and all the other names which might conflict with that name.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Yes, as you mentioned, it may generate `global::` to ensure everything is going well.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why exactly it does this, but I had the same problem. What I noticed is the error appeared when I opened an old project, pasted in new code from another project, and then when it's run it even says, "hello world".

This led me to believe that Visual Studio somehow was reading the originally generated code. I created a new project, pasted the same code, and suddenly the cw works as it was intended.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

tl;wr - Close and reopen your tabs, then it'll work as new (if your issue was the same as mine)

I had this same issue after a weird Visual Studio crash and I decided to move my code to a new location.

It turned out that Visual Studio had old tabs with code open, and it was within these old tabs that snippets like cw gave me the global::System.Console.WriteLine() code and the normal color coding stopped working.

You can actually see it if you hover your mouse over some of the old tabs, it'll show you the path of the file. So when I simply closed the tab/file and reopened that same file from the solution explorer, everything worked fine :)

Hope it helps any who runs into this silly situation before you start editing the XML and paths of your solution etc. like a certain someone else.

Comment: This was a simple bug that fixed with new minor version of Visual Studio 2022